# React: is this a good way to implement a shared state subscription?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure if this is a so-called "pub/sub" pattern or a form of a "pub/sub" pattern. I am trying to create a piece of shared state so that different components can subscribe to it and only gets updated when there is an update with that state.

```js
const useForceUpdate = () => useReducer((state) => !state, false)[1];

const createSharedState = (reducer, initialState) => {
  const subscribers = [];
  let state = initialState;
  const dispatch = (action) => {
    state = reducer(state, action);
    subscribers.forEach((callback) => callback());
  };
  const useSharedState = () => {
    const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
    useEffect(() => {
      const callback = () => forceUpdate();
      subscribers.push(callback);
      const cleanup = () => {
        const index = subscribers.indexOf(callback);
        subscribers.splice(index, 1);
      };
      return cleanup;
    }, []);
    return [state, dispatch];
  };
  return useSharedState;
};

const initialState = 0;
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return state + 1;
    case "decrement":
      return state - 1;
    case "set":
      return action.count;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const useCount1 = createSharedState(reducer, initialState);
const useCount2 = createSharedState(reducer, initialState);

const Counter = ({ count, dispatch }) => (
  <div>
    {count}
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>+1</button>
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrement" })}>-1</button>
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "set", count: 0 })}>reset</button>
  </div>
);

const Counter1 = () => {
  const [count, dispatch] = useCount1();
  return <Counter count={count} dispatch={dispatch} />;
};

const Counter2 = () => {
  const [count, dispatch] = useCount2();
  return <Counter count={count} dispatch={dispatch} />;
};

const Example = () => (
  <>
    <Counter1 />
    <Counter1 />
    <Counter2 />
    <Counter2 />
  </>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const { useEffect, useReducer } = React;

const useForceUpdate = () => useReducer((state) => !state, false)[1];

const createSharedState = (reducer, initialState) => {
  const subscribers = [];
  let state = initialState;
  const dispatch = (action) => {
    state = reducer(state, action);
    subscribers.forEach((callback) => callback());
  };
  const useSharedState = () => {
    const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
    useEffect(() => {
      const callback = () => forceUpdate();
      subscribers.push(callback);
      const cleanup = () => {
        const index = subscribers.indexOf(callback);
        subscribers.splice(index, 1);
      };
      return cleanup;
    }, []);
    return [state, dispatch];
  };
  return useSharedState;
};

const initialState = 0;
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return state + 1;
    case "decrement":
      return state - 1;
    case "set":
      return action.count;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const useCount1 = createSharedState(reducer, initialState);
const useCount2 = createSharedState(reducer, initialState);

const Counter = ({ count, dispatch }) => (
  <div>
    {count}
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>+1</button>
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrement" })}>-1</button>
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "set", count: 0 })}>reset</button>
  </div>
);

const Counter1 = () => {
  const [count, dispatch] = useCount1();
  return <Counter count={count} dispatch={dispatch} />;
};

const Counter2 = () => {
  const [count, dispatch] = useCount2();
  return <Counter count={count} dispatch={dispatch} />;
};

const Example = () => (
  <>
    <Counter1 />
    <Counter1 />
    <Counter2 />
    <Counter2 />
  </>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.querySelector("#root"));
</script>
```

It seems to be working fine. My questions are:

1. Is this a valid way to implement shared update subscription?
2. Is there any drawbacks with using a simple variable to hold the state + forcing React to re-render if that piece of state changes, instead of using `useState` or `useReducer` as one normally would do?
3. any feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Check how MobX works. You may pass it as props to your components and wrap them in observe(). MobX will handle the pub/sub for you.

Answer (score 6):

1. Your idea is excellent. React team was also thinking on this topic and ended up with the creation of https://recoiljs.org/. You can use it as `useState` ([DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-heyrovsky-vzhpt?file=/src/App.js)) or as `useReducer` ([DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-snow-z4pm8?file=/src/App.js)).
2. I don't want to highlight your solution's drawbacks. Instead, I'd like to list the advantages of using Recoil:

- Internal memory usage optimization.
- No need to support the code (Facebook does it).
- No cheating (useForceUpdate).
- Supports selectors out of the box.

3. I'd recommend you to learn more about Recoil and start using it because it gives the exact result you want to achieve.